# Is there a way to add arbitrary records to kube-dns?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I will use a very specific way to explain my problem, but I think this is better to be specific than explain in an abstract way...

Say, there is a MongoDB replica set outside of a Kubernetes cluster but in a network. The ip addresses of all members of the replica set were resolved by /etc/hosts in app servers and db servers.

In an experiment/transition phase, I need to access those mongo db servers from kubernetes pods.
However, kubernetes doesn't seem to allow adding custom entries to /etc/hosts in pods/containers.

The MongoDB replica sets are already working with large data set, creating a new replica set in the cluster is not an option.

Because I use GKE, changing any of resources in kube-dns namespace should be avoided I suppose. Configuring or replace kube-dns to be suitable for my need are last thing to try.

Is there a way to resolve ip address of custom hostnames in a Kubernetes cluster?

It is just an idea, but if kube2sky can read some entries of configmap and use them as dns records, it colud be great.
e.g. `repl1.mongo.local: 192.168.10.100`.

EDIT: I referenced this question from https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/12337

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE: 2017-07-03 Kunbernetes 1.7 now support [Adding entries to Pod /etc/hosts with HostAliases](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/).

---

The solution is not about kube-dns, but /etc/hosts.
Anyway, following trick seems to work so far...

EDIT: Changing /etc/hosts may has race condition with kubernetes system. Let it retry.

1) create a configMap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: db-hosts
data:
  hosts: |
    10.0.0.1  db1
    10.0.0.2  db2
```

2) Add a script named `ensure_hosts.sh`.

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                           
while true
do
    grep db1 /etc/hosts > /dev/null || cat /mnt/hosts.append/hosts >> /etc/hosts
    sleep 5
done
```

Don't forget `chmod a+x ensure_hosts.sh`.

3) Add a wrapper script `start.sh` your image

```
#!/bin/sh
$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")/ensure_hosts.sh &
exec your-app args...
```

Don't forget `chmod a+x start.sh`

4) Use the configmap as a volume and run start.sh

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: hosts-volume
        configMap:
          name: db-hosts
      ...
      containers:
        command:
        - ./start.sh
        ...
        volumeMounts:
        - name: hosts-volume
          mountPath: /mnt/hosts.append
        ...
```

Comment: It's a satisfactory hack for a temporary deployment which allows for quick and dirty updates. The other answers are better, especially @0xMH's answer

Answer (score 42):

There are 2 possible solutions for this problem now:

1. Pod-wise (Adding the changes to every pod needed to resolve these domains)
2. cluster-wise (Adding the changes to a central place which all pods have access to, Which is in our case is the `DNS`)

#### Let's begin with the pod-wise solution:

As of Kunbernetes 1.7, It's possible now to add entries to a Pod's `/etc/hosts` directly using `.spec.hostAliases`

For example: to resolve `foo.local`, `bar.local` to `127.0.0.1` and `foo.remote`,
`bar.remote` to `10.1.2.3`, you can configure HostAliases for a Pod under
`.spec.hostAliases`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hostaliases-pod
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "127.0.0.1"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.local"
    - "bar.local"
  - ip: "10.1.2.3"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.remote"
    - "bar.remote"
  containers:
  - name: cat-hosts
    image: busybox
    command:
    - cat
    args:
    - "/etc/hosts"
```

#### The Cluster-wise solution:

As of Kubernetes v1.12, `CoreDNS` is the recommended DNS Server, replacing `kube-dns.` If your cluster originally used `kube-dns`, you may still have `kube-dns` deployed rather than `CoreDNS`. I'm going to assume that you're using `CoreDNS` as your K8S DNS.

In CoreDNS it's possible to Add an arbitrary entries inside the cluster domain and that way all pods will resolve this entries directly from the DNS without the need to change each and every `/etc/hosts` file in every pod.

**First:**

Let's change the coreos ConfigMap and add required changes:

```
kubectl edit cm coredns -n kube-system 

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
          lameduck 5s
        }
        hosts /etc/coredns/customdomains.db example.org {
          fallthrough
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
          pods insecure
          fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . "/etc/resolv.conf"
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
  customdomains.db: |
    10.10.1.1 mongo-en-1.example.org
    10.10.1.2 mongo-en-2.example.org
    10.10.1.3 mongo-en-3.example.org
    10.10.1.4 mongo-en-4.example.org
```

Basically we added two things:

1. The `hosts` plugin before the `kubernetes` plugin and used the `fallthrough` option of the `hosts` plugin to satisfy our case.

   To shed some more lights on the `fallthrough` option.  Any given backend is usually the final word for its zone - it either returns a result, or it returns NXDOMAIN for the
   query. However, occasionally this is not the desired behavior, so some of the plugin support a `fallthrough` option.
   When `fallthrough` is enabled, instead of returning NXDOMAIN when a record is not found, the plugin will pass the
   request down the chain. A backend further down the chain then has the opportunity to handle the request and that backend in our case is `kubernetes`.
2. We added a new file to the ConfigMap (`customdomains.db`) and added our custom domains (`mongo-en-*.example.org`) in there.

Last thing is to Remember to add the `customdomains.db` file to the `config-volume` for the CoreDNS pod template:

```
kubectl edit -n kube-system deployment coredns
```

```
volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: coredns
            items:
            - key: Corefile
              path: Corefile
            - key: customdomains.db
              path: customdomains.db
```

and finally to make kubernetes reload CoreDNS (each pod running):

```
$ kubectl rollout restart -n kube-system deployment/coredns
```

Comment: I just posted an answer based on yours but inlining the hosts rather than defining them in a different file. I wondered if you had considered this method, and if there was any reason you preferred to define the hosts in a separate file.

Comment: What about kube-dns which is mentioned in the title of this question?

Comment: CoreDNS is not a practical option on GKE... I'm here to try and figure out a solution on GKE's kube-dns , similar to what I did on CoreDNS and this answers a different question that the one in the title... HostAliases does not scale...

Comment: Too late for edit: https://cloud.google.com/knowledge/kb/how-to-run-coredns-on-kubernetes-engine-000004698
"Note: This is not a Google Cloud supported solution, but just a possible workaround for providing your Google Kubernetes Engine cluster CoreDNS resolution. "

Answer (score 28):

@OxMH answer is fantastic, and can be simplified for brevity. CoreDNS allows you to specify hosts directly in the hosts plugin (https://coredns.io/plugins/hosts/#examples).

The ConfigMap can therefore be edited like so:

```
$ kubectl edit cm coredns -n kube-system 


apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
          lameduck 5s
        }
        hosts {
          10.10.1.1 mongo-en-1.example.org
          10.10.1.2 mongo-en-2.example.org
          10.10.1.3 mongo-en-3.example.org
          10.10.1.4 mongo-en-4.example.org
          fallthrough
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
          pods insecure
          fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . "/etc/resolv.conf"
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
```

You will still need to restart coredns so it rereads the config:

```
$ kubectl rollout restart -n kube-system deployment/coredns
```

Inlining the contents of the hostsfile removes the need to map the hostsfile from the configmap. Both approaches achieve the same outcome, it is up to personal preference as to where you want to define the hosts.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. The other approach with a new file via `customdomains.db` did not work

Comment: This does not use kube-dns as in the question, it is not an option on providers that force the use of kube-dns, like GKE. (well, they also allowGoogle DNS, but that requires the cluster domain to be changed from clsuter.local (if more than one cluster is deployed)

Answer (score 10):

A type of External Name is required to access hosts or ips outside of the kubernetes.

The following worked for me.

```
{
    "kind": "Service",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "tiny-server-5",
        "namespace": "default"
    },
    "spec": {
        "type": "ExternalName",
        "externalName": "192.168.1.15",
        "ports": [{ "port": 80 }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use this! externalName should only point to an external name, such as a DNS record. See note in K8S docs: "ExternalName accepts an IPv4 address string, but as a DNS name comprised of digits, not as an IP address. ExternalNames that resemble IPv4 addresses are not resolved by CoreDNS or ingress-nginx because ExternalName is intended to specify a canonical DNS name. To hardcode an IP address, consider headless services." (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname)

morallo's answer is correct.

Answer (score 7):

For the record, an alternate solution for those not checking the referenced [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/12337).

You can define an "external" Service in Kubernetes, by not specifying any selector or ClusterIP. You have to also define a corresponding Endpoint pointing to your external IP.

From the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#services-without-selectors):

```
{
    "kind": "Service",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "my-service"
    },
    "spec": {
        "ports": [
            {
                "protocol": "TCP",
                "port": 80,
                "targetPort": 9376
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "kind": "Endpoints",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "my-service"
    },
    "subsets": [
        {
            "addresses": [
                { "ip": "1.2.3.4" }
            ],
            "ports": [
                { "port": 9376 }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

With this, you can point your app inside the containers to `my-service:9376` and the traffic should be forwarded to `1.2.3.4:9376`

Limitations:

- The DNS name used needs to be **only letters, numbers or dashes**. You can't use multi-level names (`something.like.this`). This means you probably have to modify your app to point just to `your-service`, and not `yourservice.domain.tld`.
- You can only point to a specific IP, not a DNS name. For that, you can define a kind of a DNS alias with an `ExternalName` type Service.

Comment: Thanks. This info will be help if hostname -> ip mapping is needed.

Comment: This breaks TLS certificate validation - A cert issued by an external CA likely contains the external hostname, so if you point this to an internal IP, the certificate validation will fail.

Answer (score 2):

Use configMap seems better way to set DNS, but it's a little bit heavy when just add a few record (in my opinion). So I add records to `/etc/hosts` by shell script executed by docker `CMD`.

for example:

Dockerfile

```
...(ignore)
COPY run.sh /tmp/run.sh
CMD bash /tmp/run.sh
```

run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo repl1.mongo.local 192.168.10.100 >> /etc/hosts
# some else command...
```

Notice, if your run MORE THAN ONE container in a pod, you have to **add script in each container**, because kubernetes start container randomly, `/etc/hosts` may be override by another container (which start later).

Comment: Ah, multiple containers in a pod can overwrite /etc/hosts... it seems... Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Mounting the hosts file from a shared volume might make more sense with multiple container pods (and hostAliases is the more modern way to do it). As is, it also requires the pod to be running as root, which is a security risk.

Answer (score -1):

i was running k3s cluster and get one simple solution

```
$ kubectl edit cm coredns -n kube-system
```

get this file open

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
          pods insecure
          fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        hosts /etc/coredns/NodeHosts {
          ttl 60
          reload 15s
          fallthrough
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
        import /etc/coredns/custom/*.override
    }
    import /etc/coredns/custom/*.server
  NodeHosts: |
    10.0.0.248 k8s-master-node
    10.0.0.198 my-custom-hostname   # <- add my dns here
kind: ConfigMap
```

save this file & run

```
$ kubectl rollout restart -n kube-system deployment/coredns
```

and now i can resolve **my-custom-hostname** to **10.0.0.198** from any pod

Comment: CoreDNS is the better alternative to kube-dns. Some providers (GKE) does not provide CoreDNS as an option, which is why this question is specifically asking about kube-dns.