# Create specific A record entry to Kubernetes local DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, kubernetes, kube-dns

I have a Kubernetes v1.4 cluster running in AWS with auto-scaling nodes.
I also have a Mongo Replica Set cluster with SSL-only connections (FQDN common-name) and public DNS entries:

- node1.mongo.example.com -> 1.1.1.1
- node2.mongo.example.com -> 1.1.1.2
- node3.mongo.example.com -> 1.1.1.3

The Kubernetes nodes are part of a security group that allows access to the mongo cluster, but only via their private IPs.

Is there a way of creating A records in the Kubernetes DNS with the private IPs when the public FQDN is queried?

The first thing I tried was a script & ConfigMap combination to update /etc/hosts on startup (ref. [Is it a way to add arbitrary record to kube-dns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166822/is-it-a-way-to-add-arbitrary-record-to-kube-dns)), but that is problematic as other Kubernetes services may also update the hosts file at different times.

I also tried a Services & Enpoints configuration:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: node1.mongo.example.com
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: node1.mongo.example.com
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.168.0.1
    ports:
      - port: 27017
```

But this fails as the Service name cannot be a FQDN...

Comment: Have you thought of using the mongo instance AWS public DNS (public hostname)? It redirects to the private IP when called from an ec2 instance: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#vpc-public-ip-addresses

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While not so obvious at first, the solution is quite simple. kube-dns image in recent versions includes `dnsmasq` as one of it's components. If you look into its man page, you will see some usefull options. Following that lecture you can choose a path similar to this :

Create a ConfigMap to store your dns mappings :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: kube-dns
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  myhosts: |
    10.0.0.1 foo.bar.baz
```

Having that ConfigMap applied in your cluster you can now make some changes to `kube-dns-vXX` deployment you use in your kubernetes.

Define volume that will expose your CM to `dnsmasq`

```
  volumes:
  - name: hosts
    configMap:
      name: kube-dns
```

and mount is in your `dnsmasq` container of `kube-dns` deployment/rc template

```
    volumeMounts:
    - name: hosts
      mountPath: /etc/hosts.d
```

and finally, add a small config flag to your dnsmasq arguments :

```
    args:
    - --hostsdir=/etc/hosts.d
```

now, as you apply these changes to the `kube-dns-vXX` deployment in your cluster it will mount the configmap and use files mounted in /etc/hosts.d/ (with typical hosts file format) as a source of knowledge for `dnsmasq`. Hence if you now query for foo.bar.baz in your pods, they will resolve to respective IP. These entries take precedence over public DNS, so it should perfectly fit your case.

Mind that `dnsmasq` is not watching for changes in ConfigMap so it has to be restarted manually if it changes.

Tested and validated this on a live cluster just few minutes ago.

Comment: The only solution that's worked for me on trying to add my own DNS A Records to kube-dns.