# Resolving random name to random ip for in kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

I have a kube claster deployed in my VM. I would like that kube pods be able to resolve the VM host name. I know that kubernetes resolves names by DNS but I have no any DNS. 
I would like to know is there any way to configure kube-dns that it resolves random name to random ip. 
For example: I want that name "foo" is resolved to "1.2.3.4" for all pods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to add arbitrary records to kube-dns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166822/is-there-a-way-to-add-arbitrary-records-to-kube-dns)

Comment: No it doesn't. I really need a DNS solution.

Comment: so do you want pods to resolve it to vm host or to random IP?

Comment: Precisely I want any pod could resolve vm host name