# Add custom dns record inside Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, host, coredns

Is it possible to add a custom DNS entry (type A) inside Kubernetes 1.19? I'd like to be able to do:

```
kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never --image=infoblox/dnstools:latest dnstools
host custom-dns-entry.example.com
custom-dns-entry.example.com has address 10.0.0.72
```

with `custom-dns-entry.example.com` not being registered inside my upstream DNS server (and also not having a corresponding k8s service at all).
Following example https://coredns.io/2017/05/08/custom-dns-entries-for-kubernetes/ seems to provide a solution, but it is a bit complex and it may be deprecated. Is there a simpler way to do it please? For example with a few `kubectl` commands?

*The reason why I need this is because I run my workload on `kind` so my ingress DNS record is not registered inside upstream DNS and some pods require access to this ingress DNS record from inside (maybe to configure a javascript client provided by the pods which will effectively access the ingress DNS record from outside...). However I cannot modify the workload code as I am not maintaining it, so addgin this custom DNS entry seems to be a reasonable solution*

Comment: Would mounting /etc/hosts file to pods solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

CoreDNS would be the place to do this. You can also do similar-ish things using ExternalName-type Services but that wouldn't give you full control over the hostname (it would be a Service name like anything else).

Comment: Yes and this post looks like a good track: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65338650/2784039